# How to implement twitter login functionality on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've already tried to use Facebook login functionality. During the login I got user token and using this token I could identify user. So, Facebook is OK for me.

---

1) How can I implement login functionality with Twitter? Will I get anything the same like user token on Facebook?

As far as I know, to use twitter API user should be login in twitter in the settings of iPhone. Can I implement anything to enable user to login even he is not yet logged in in the settings of iPhone?

2) After user login I want him to invite his twitter friends to my application. Is it possible to do? And in what ways?

I will be grateful for some code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the link below each and every step is clearly told by Twitter itself.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios

If you still having problem please follow the link 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5

That contains the code and all steps !

Hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this [link](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Compose-Tweets)
it will provide stepwise details.

add

```
 #import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
```

Then you can tweet something using:

```
 -(IBAction)tweetTapped:(id)sender { 
{
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = 
            [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:
            @"Tweeting from iOS 5 By Tutorials! :)"];
        [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
            initWithTitle:@"Sorry"                                                             
            message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure  
                your device has an internet connection and you have 
                at least one Twitter account setup"                                                          
            delegate:self                                              
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"                                                   
            otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to tweet, I want to login and get login information. My application is social network, and I want to provide ability to login through twitter

Comment: Access denied for link